# How to scroll text in UITextView like teleprompter in swift?

Tags: swift, uitextview, uidynamicanimator

I want to scroll my text like teleprompter scroll. I've read about `UIDynamicAnimation` but not clear with `UITextView` for multiple lines.

Appreciate your suggestions or code snippets to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive method we could animate each row scroll using `UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:completed)` till we reach the end of the textView.

```
func animateRowWith(duration: TimeInterval, rowHeight: CGFloat) {
    if self.textView.contentOffset.y < self.textView.contentSize.height - self.textView.frame.size.height {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.textView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.textView.contentOffset.x, y: self.textView.contentOffset.y + rowHeight)
        }) { (_) in
            self.animateRowWith(duration: duration, rowHeight: rowHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

calling it:

`animateRowWith(duration: 1.0, rowHeight: self.textView.font?.lineHeight ?? 0)`.

Note that you will have a delay after each row has scrolled.

Comment: This will also work, Deyck. But I'm looking for `UIDynamicAnimation` solution. But anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi @SunilTarge, can you please answer your own question and tell us how you did it with UIDynamicAnimation?

Comment: @ozd I didn't find a way to do with UITextView, So I tried using UILabel to set sizetofit property and animate it using UIPushBehaviour. It works great but having some blocker like user can't control scroll up down by swipe up/down while UIPushBehaviour is going on. You can also please answer here if you found any alternative solution to this problem.